# Poincaré Map Nonlinear Pendulum with Torque

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

Suppose we have the following system
$$ \theta'=v $$
$$ v'= -bv - \sin\theta + k. $$
I can find the equilibria and the bk-parameter plane of this system, but this question I don't know how to approach.

Suppose we have the line where $\theta = 0$, what can be said about the qualitative features of the Poincaré map along this line?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the energy function  $ E(\theta , v)=1/2 v^2 +1-cos(\theta) $ .

And let  $ p $  is the Poincaré map.
We have a periodic orbit if  $ p (v)=v  $  for some v.

On the other hand $ dE/ d\theta = k-bv. $ 
so a periodic orbit exist if the total energy is zero.

And hence  $ \int_{0}^{2\pi} (dE/ d\theta ) d\theta =0  $  when $ \int_{0}^{2\pi}   v d\theta = 2k\pi /b  $ .
Notice that if  $ v'<v $  then $ \int_{0}^{2\pi}   v'  d\theta  $ < $ \int_{0}^{2\pi}   v d\theta  $  and same as if  $ v'>v $ , this means there is a unique v.

For some initial value  $(0,v_{0}) $ .

If  $ v_{0}< v $  ( the trajectory through the initial value is insitde the periodic orbit) then $ p$ is increasing ( since E'>0).
If   $ v_{0}> v $  (the trajectory is outside of the periodic orbit ) thenp is decreasing  ( E'<0)
In both two cases p tend to the fixed point v which yelds the periodic orbit.